# All new HTML appears behind an image?

Tags: html, css

I have been working on a responsive web design, after adding CSS to make a link stay centered on a an image the webpage now displays any new html behind the image. I want to be able to add more things on my webpage but any new html I write disappears.
`Link to JSFIDDLE`https://jsfiddle.net/R4bbit2k17/7yuL4y1p/1/#&togetherjs=MEzytpw3kf`

Answer (score 2):

Because your `.banner-inner` is using **[`position: absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#absolute)** in conjunction with taking up `100%` of the **[`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)** and **[`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)**, you'll need to set a `position` other than static for your text element(s), along with giving them a **[`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)** greater than the default of `0`:

```
p {
  background: red; /* Purely to highlight the text */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

This causes your text to appear on top of your image, and can be seen in the following:

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

header {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 20px;
  min-height: 45px;
}

header a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
}

header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1000px) {
  .centered {
    font-size: 12pt!important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:800px) {
  .centered {
    font-size: 11pt!important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .centered {
    font-size: 10pt!important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:400px) {
  .centered {
    font-size: 9pt!important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:200px) {
  .centered {
    font-size: 8pt!important;
  }
}

.banner-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 20%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12pt;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}

p {
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div id="header-inner">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="courses.html" class="current">Courses</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html" class="current">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section class="section-1">
    <div class="banner-inner">
      <img class="img" alt="" src="https://d2mt0dng9y3p4j.cloudfront.net/newandimproved/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/shop-with-a-sheriff-mockup.jpg">
      <div class="centered"><a href="courses.html">Start Learning</a></div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <p>ANY HTML ADDED APPEARS BEHIND THE IMAGE AND I CANNOT FIGURE OUT HOW TO CHANGE IT TO APPEAR BENEATH THE IMAGE AS IT WOULD WITH A FRESH HTML PAGE</p>
</body>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for solving that problem now the other problem I have is that everything new I code is at the top of the page and doesn't just start under the image like it would in a fresh html page with no formatting

Comment: That's a caveat of `position: absolute`; it takes the element out of the flow. What you're looking for in that regard is `position: relative` instead.

Comment: Okay so basically I am looking for is to have an image and a link over that image, I want the website to be responsive and I need the link to stay in the center of my image no matter if I view the website on a desktop, laptop whatever it may be I just need the "start learning" link to stay in the middle of the image and not jump around the page when viewed on different devices. I also want to be able to add more html and css without it disrupting the link over the image. I need to add a 4 column section right below the image so I really need help with understanding how to do this correctly

Comment: Obsidian you actually did answer my problem it just took a second to play with my code... thank you so much!